# Como verificar se houve algum erro no POST

Tags: android, post, asynctask

Preciso verificar se houve algum erro na resposta do onPostExecute ou deu time out no servidor, pois as vezes dá algum erro no processo e esse método não chega nem a iniciar, como eu poderia fazezr tal verificação?

Eu o chamo assim:

```
 ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                url = "https://...";

                parametros = "paramentro=" + string;

                new minhaclasse.SolicitaDados().execute(url);

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro, tente novamente!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

E então ele executa:

```
private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametros);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {

        if(resultado != null && resultado != "") {

        }
    }
}
```

Classe de conexão:

```
  public class Conexao {

  public static String postDados(String urlUsuario, String parametrosUsuario) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {

        url = new URL(urlUsuario);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Lenght", "" + Integer.toString(parametrosUsuario.getBytes().length));

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "pt-BR");

        //connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter outPutStream = new 
        OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "utf-8");
        outPutStream.write(parametrosUsuario);
        outPutStream.flush();
        outPutStream.close();

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));

        String linha;
        StringBuffer resposta = new StringBuffer();

        while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         resposta.append(linha);
            resposta.append('\r');
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        return resposta.toString();

    } catch (Exception erro) {

        return  null;
    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Se você colocar o trecho de código do 'doInBackground' dentro de um bloco try-catch resolveria? Não fiz os testes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que sua `AsyncTask` está retornando um valor:

```
// Instancia o obj
SolicitaDados obj = new SolicitaDados();
// Executa a classe `AssyncTask`
obj.execute();
// Puxa o retorno (se for int)
int retorno = obj.get();
```

O `get()` irá esperar o término da `doInBackground`, e retornar seu `onPostExecute`.

[AsyncTask - final Result](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Complementando:

O código está correto, só faltando tratar um timeout do `HttpURLConnection` para não ficar rodando sem previsão por qualquer que seja o motivo.

Exemplo:

```
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(3000); 
httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000); 
httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true); 
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true); 
httpURLConnection.connect();
```

Comment: Olá, bom dia amigo, não entendi muito bem o funcionamento desse trecho de código, pode me explicar melhor?

Comment: Alterei a resposta. Mas se quiser mais completa, poste suas class completas, funcionando, se não, não temos como exemplificar em cima do seu código.

Comment: Ah, agora entendi, mas eu já recebia o retorno na String resultado do onPostExecute, eu gostaria de saber como verificar se deu time out, por exemplo durante o processo

Comment: @WotonSampaio aí depende da sua estrutura de como está solicitando. Vou postar um exemplo com o `httpURLConnection`

Comment: Olha, vou postar a class da conexão, só um momento

Comment: Do jeito que estou fazendo, antes de fazer o post ele verifica se tem internet, mas caso a pessoa esteja conectada em uma rede que não tenha internet, ele vai ficar o resto da vida fazendo o processo, não crasha, apenas fica carregando infinitamente

Comment: O teste da conexão, seria melhor fazer antes de chamar o método. Se tem conexão, chama, se não tem, não chama.

Comment: Dá uma olhada agora, botei como estou testando a conexão e a class

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74921/discussion-between-rbz-and-woton-sampaio).